# Reloading a page after editing hashtag pressing enter

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I made a page where there are two tabs. Login and Register. I am willing to open a specific tab for a specific hashtag after main url. Like, if I write,
http://someurl.com/user.html#login
it should open login tab and if I write,
http://someurl.com/user.html#register
When I come to user.html page from another page using the url, it works fine. But, when I am in user.html and I just edit the hashtag and press ENTER, first time it doesn't work. But, it works for second time. Also, if i reload the page, it works fine. Problem is with Pressing ENTER.
Any solution ?

Comment: You will ALWAYS get better help if you show us the specific code you're using for handling the hash tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us what code you're using, but you can use something like [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) to be notified any time the hash changes and your code can then do whatever you want based on the new hash value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `window.onhashchange`. However, it does not support older type browser such as IE 6/7.

If you want to make it cross browser, you can use this [jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/). Basically, the plugins use `setInterval` if the browser does not support `window.onhashchange`